# Two same sized elements displaying different width

Tags: html, css

I'm laying out a website design and I have run into an error...

The html element is assigned a fixed width of 800px, the body element ID 'page' will not take up 100% width no matter what I try?

Heres the code...

```
<html>
<body id="page" >
    / content /
</body>
</html>


html {
    width: 800px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#page {

}
```

I have tried setting the #page to 'width:800px',  'width:100%',  'margin:0',  'margin:0 auto', etc. but no matter what there is always a 1px gap on the right side of #page. I've even tried setting 'width:801px' which didn't work, as well as setting the relative position left 1px in case it was overflowing left for some reason, but it's not...

Am I missing something stupid, is the program I am using buggy, or is it something else? Where I am from, 800px is the same as 800px so what's going on?

Thanks guys....

EDIT:
So, going back through previous projects I discovered what works for me. Whether it be the program I am using(free), or just something I'm missing this is what works for me and so resolves my issue.

```
<html>
<body>
/ content /
</body>
</html>

html {
    width: 800px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a border applied?

Comment: Only just started styling, that's literally all the css I have at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some extra css sneaking in somewhere. Check for any `border` property on your #page element.

Run this snippet, and there shouldn't be a single pixel gap.

```css
html {
  width: 800px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

#page {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body id="page">
  / content /
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The css shown above is literally all there is, but I tried your suggestion with no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

it appears you are running into an inconsistency problem in the way browsers inject scrollbars into the page, see here:

[Styling the `<html>` element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593106/styling-the-html-element-in-css)

I would start by using a css reset like normalize.css to get cross-browser consistency in behaviour then use your custom styles from there. Personally I never style the html element and work from the body down. Working like that I dont encounter these kinds of problems becuase they are dealt with by normalize.css.

Comment: I've never had this issue previously, so a css reset shouldn't be necessary(for now). I've looked back over previous works and found that the styling only works for me by setting the width of html and a 0 margin on body. I'll update my post with the 'answer'.

Comment: OK, but perhaps give it a try: Remove your own html styles, add normaliser, then style as required. If you style from the body down then normalize.css should ensure the correct behaviour on your html element.